# After Upgrading Wamp Images in Storage Not Showing 404 not found

Tags: laravel, wamp, storage, laravel-blade

I am facing a weird problem I am recently upgraded wamp server , but i find out that image dosn't load  as it was before upgrading , when I open the image URL in the browser it showing error 404 : page not found

here is my code :

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/profile_pics/'.$user->profile_pic) }}" class="img-responsive" alt=""> </div>
```

any help ?

Comment: Did you create symbolic link via `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: yes I did that before upgrade when I try to create it now it says already created

Comment: Do you have image you are accessing inside `storage/app/public/profile_pics`?

Comment: of course I have it was work fine before upgrading the wamp

Comment: Is your new apache config using `Options FollowSymLinks`?

Comment: update the APP_URL=http://localhost in .env file

Answer (score 0):

in your .env file add your APP_URL = to your root folder url which u use to get to your laravel app through WAMP server.
if it doesn't work

You can configure the asset URL host by setting the ASSET_URL variable in your .env file. This can be useful if you host your assets on an external service like Amazon S3:

// ASSET_URL=http://example.com/assets

```
$url = asset('img/photo.jpg'); // http://example.com/assets/img/photo.jpg
```

according to this:-
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-asset

P.S: if you use the command

```
php artisan serve
```

and update your APP_URL in your .env file to localhost:8000 , it will work just fine.